# PySide6 How to move QGraphicsWidget?

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, pyside6

I am kicking off with PySide6 and struggling to get my first GraphicsView/Scene and Items working.

Since the system provides lots of methods and flags, my first assumption was that in order to move a widget I would only need to enable the widget being moved by activating the flag IsMovable. However I am only being able to move the widget around if manually calling to moveBy().

This doesn't look right to me, then otherwhise why should I need to set that flag?

Here's my code. Please be patient I am starting with it.

What am I missing for the widget to move around without calls to moveBy() or any alternative methods? I am trying to use the functionality PySide6 is supposed to bring out of the box.

I am also trying to grasp some intuitions from the example in:

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-graphicsview-elasticnodes-example.html#elastic-nodes-example

But there seems to be no full code there. Any ideas where can I get source code for those examples?

Many thanks for your help and please do not pay much attention to any indent errors in the code (just saving the time to add blankspaces around)

Regards,
Carlos.

```
import sys

import PySide6
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt, QCursor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QApplication, QGraphicsItem, 
QGraphicsWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import QRect, QPointF


class MyItem(QGraphicsWidget):



def __init__(self, node_item):
    super().__init__(parent=None)
    self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, False)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsWidget.ItemIsMovable, True)
    self.setFlag(QGraphicsWidget.ItemIsSelectable, True)

    self.offset : QPointF = None

def boundingRect(self) -> PySide6.QtCore.QRectF:
    return QRect(0,0,30,30)

def paint(self, painter: PySide6.QtGui.QPainter, option: PySide6.QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget) -> None:
    r = QRect(0, 0, 30, 30)
    painter.drawRect(r)


def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor))
    self.moveBy(event.pos().x() - self.offset.x(), event.pos().y() - self.offset.y())



def mousePressEvent(self, event: PySide6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent) -> None:

    self.setSelected(True)
    scene.update(self.boundingRect())
    self.offset = QPointF(event.pos()-self.pos())

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event: PySide6.QtWidgets.QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent) -> None:
    self.setSelected(False)
    self.update(self.boundingRect())

def grabMouseEvent(self, event: PySide6.QtCore.QEvent) -> None:
    print("object grabbed")




app = QApplication()

scene = QGraphicsScene()
item = MyItem(scene)
scene.addItem(item)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)

scene.setSceneRect(0, 0 ,1000, 1000)

view.geometry().setHeight(500)
view.geometry().setWidth(500)

view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: If you override the mouse event handler, then you're *ignoring* the default behavior. Since the movement of the item is caused by mouse events, you're preventing it from moving by *not* calling the default implementation. Add `super()` calls to each mouse event handlers (`super().mouseMoveEvent(event)` etc). Also, `boundingRect()` should return a QRectF type, not QRect.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Pretty obvious answer but didn't see that. Thanks for your indications.